# File ended while scanning use of \bibcite out of nowhere

Tags: errors

I've been working on a thesis on my MacBook Air with OS X Sierra for several weeks already...always in the same TexShop 3.8 file.

Today, out of nowhere, the file stopped to compile and gives me the error:

'Runaway argument? ./Bachelorarbeit.tex:37: File ended while scanning use of \bibcite.  \par l.37 \begin{document}'

The strange thing about that is that 'undo' did not work to make it compile again and that moving '\end{document}' to the line right under '\begin{document}' did not work either. When I paste the code into a new file it works for several compilations but stops compiling out of nowhere again. Also the file compiles in Overleaf. Because of that and since I double-checked it I'm sure I did not forget a '}' anywhere.

The .aux file's last two lines are:
\bibcite{Marvi et al. 2011}{38}
\bibcite

but I cannot find anything remarkable in my 38th or 39th reference.

I appreciate every help you guys can give me.

Thank you
Jonas

edit:
@TeXnician These are the packages I'm currently using. Do you think there's an issue with them?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} %to make it an article

\usepackage{a4wide} %for width

\usepackage[a4paper, left=25mm, right=25mm, top=30mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry} %for space left, right, top, bottom

\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel} %for different languages   

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}%for umlauts

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %for german stuff

\usepackage{lmodern} %for prettier signs in pdf

\usepackage{amsmath} %for mathematical expression

\usepackage{graphicx} %for images

\usepackage{tabularx} %for tables

\usepackage{upgreek} %for special greek signs

\usepackage{diagbox} %for diagonal lines in tables

\usepackage{xcolor} %for colored signs

\usepackage{colortbl} %for colored tables

\usepackage{lscape}  %for large tables

\usepackage{caption} %for captions

\usepackage{eurosym} %for euro symbol

\usepackage{scrpage2} %for header and footer

\usepackage{here} %to insert at a certain point

\usepackage{rotating} %to rotate

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %to transfer references to pdf or something like that

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} %Zeilenabstand 

\usepackage{scrpage2} %Kopfzeile

\usepackage{acronym} %for nomenclature

\usepackage{bm} %for bf in math environment

\usepackage[framed, numbered]{matlab-prettifier} %for pretty matlab code
```

Comment: just delete the aux file

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks first of all. It helped and the file is compiling again. But I have to delete the .aux file every time I caused an error now. Is there a way to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Probably not, because the packages you're using seem to have problems with their aux-writes if you have an error.

Comment: you presumably get a real error that stopped the run while it was writing the file (which is how the aux file became corrupt) if you made an example or at least showed the fill text of that error from the log, someone could help

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not sure which part of the .log file I should copy and paste. Can you tell me how I can find what you would like to take a look at?

Comment: error messages start with `!` have the text of an error message over the next few lines normally ending woith `?`

Comment: Ok. You may call me crazy. There was not a single '!' neither in the .log nor in the.aux file. Delete both files, which I tried before, seems to fix the problem. Compiling works. Even after producing a forced error.

Thank you very much for your help.